# Am I able to store games downloaded from PSN onto an external hard drive

Tags: ps3, psn

I have an 80GB PS3 from 2009, and the hard drive is almost full. I recently got a PS4 as well, so I signed up to Playstation Plus but could not download and install any of the free games on my PS3 because there was no room on the HDD. I have an external HDD that is formatted to FAT32 that I can watch TV shows and Movies on through my PS3, but can I move my downloaded games onto the external HDD and install and play them from there. I also have other games that had to be installed, like GTA 5 and the Assassin's Creed heritage collection which take up heaps of room too.

Comment: Just "purchase"/activate the games from the Sony store website and download them later to the PS4 when you get it on-line. Once activated they stay available for download for the life of your PSN+ subscription.